# Is there a reliable guide online for converting a Rails 2 app to Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 2 application and I'm looking into converting it to use Rails 3.

Does there exist somewhere a coherent, accurate, and up-to-date text document **(not a screencast)** along the lines of "How to Convert a Rails 2.x Application to Rails 3"?

Or even just, "A General Guide to Converting an Application from Rails 2.x to Rails 3 Covering the Issues You'll Need To Consider and the Common Pitfalls".

(The problem with screencasts and their transcripts is that they're very difficult to update, so they don't get updated and they rapidly become unreliable.)

Comment: If you upgrade your app to Rails 3, there will be "lost time" (opportunity cost) in doing so. Given that, **why** are you upgrading? Because Rails 3 is newer? Or based on some real business need?

Comment: I'm actually reluctant to upgrade and I've been avoiding it for precisely the reason you mentioned. However, I ran into a  library that no longer supports Rails 2.x (Thinking Sphinx), so I figured I'd better at least start researching and looking into it. But, yeah, maybe it's better just to stick with Rails 2.x.

Comment: "No longer supports"? There are older versions of that library. It was developed for Rails 2 after all.

Comment: Yes, I'm using an older version. But the current Thinking Sphinx doesn't support Rails 2, only Rails 3. Fine for now, but seems like a hint that I'll need to move forward eventually.

Answer (score 5):

A great guide is the 3-part screencast series on Railscasts by Ryan Bates

http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2
http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3

ASCIICASTS :

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I mentioned in my question I'm specifically looking for a text document rather than a screencast.

Comment: A railscast, always comes with an ascii cast. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, because every application is different. [The Rails 3 Upgrade Handbook](http://peepcode.com/products/rails-3-upgrade-handbook-pdf) will get you started, as will the [rails_upgrade](http://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade) plugin.

Comment: True. Every app is different. Question updated. Unfortunately, my project requires more than just getting started, and there are hard consequences for lost time. It doesn't look like that Upgrade Guide is actively maintained. The last revision was in July of 2010. If I pay $12 for it and invest time (== $$$) in reading it, can I count on it to be up-to-date and accurate?