# Automatic converting old syntax of scopes to new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-3-upgrade

I'm working on upgrade of old code which contains a lot of deprecated code in scopes. For example:

```
scope :by_domain, lambda { |domain| {:joins => :profile_domains,
                                     :conditions => ["profile_domains.domain_id = ?", domain] }
```

It should be changed to:

```
scope :by_domain, ->(domain) { joins(:profile_domains).
                               where("profile_domains.domain_id = ?", domain) }
```

Is there some solution that automatically converts the old syntax to a new  one or developers every time correct it manually?

Comment: Oh my god, is everyone doing that nowadays? Well, we tried doing it via regex etc about a year ago and could not come to a generalized solution because of lack of consistency in the way the scopes were written. Some had other options within `:conditions` and that made it even more difficult.

Comment: May be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669986/is-there-a-reliable-guide-online-for-converting-a-rails-2-app-to-rails-3

Comment: My advice would be that the time you spend trying to automate it, including bugfixing and checking that it's actually worked properly, would be much greater than the time it would take you to just go through and change them by hand.  You can find all the instances by grepping your app/models folder (or using the search function of your IDE, if you use one).